# Anaconda-Navigator does not start from menu in Xubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.3.
Anaconda-navigator starts ok from a terminal, with just
`anaconda-navigator`, or the full path to where it is installed in
john/Downloads/python/bin (plain text document).

Using the Menu Editor to add a new item, it appears in the sub-menu (Development), but fails to start.
I have no problems with other programs added to the menu in the same way, e.g. `geany`,from `/usr/bin` (executable).

Using menulibre or alacarte does not help, either.

Is it connected with `anaconda-navigator` being plain text?

Thanks for looking, John

---

Anaconda-navigator is an IDE for python.

Added new menu item with alacarte `Xfce4-terminal -e "anaconda-navigator"` in command window. Terminal opens with message `Failed to execute command "Xfce4-terminal -s "anaconda-navigator""`. Same thing happens with `anaconda-navigator`

Comment: I have no idea what this program is, but please try `xterm -e "anaconda-navigator"` as the menu program to start. I.e. replace `anaconda-navigator` with what I just wrote. (Use your own terminal program instead of `xterm`, if you're using something different)

Comment: Thanks Al, this istallation uses Xfce4-terminal, tried substituting

Comment: no - <failed to execute child process> on terminal

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you previously because of html tags stripped in your post (I fixed them now). You should use a small letter `x` in the command: `xfce4-terminal`, not `Xfce4-terminal`. Executables (and resp. commands) are case-sensitive.

Comment: still same error, even with lower-case xfce4

Comment: Then try `xfce4-terminal -x anaconda-navigator` (see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1894293&s=5a62c8eb2e59ee68b9d56909c6f7487a&p=11534635#post11534635)

Comment: same result - "failed to execute child" when entered as a command in Main Menu|Development

Answer (score 0):

As `anaconda-navigator` uses *STDOUT*, you need to see it from somewhere - you can either redirect it to a file or to a terminal emulator.

Instead of telling the menu option to execute `anaconda-navigator`, tell it to open a terminal, and tell the terminal to execute your command:

```
xfce4-terminal -e "anaconda-navigator | less"
```

Put this in the field for the command to execute in the menu action.

I used `| less` to pipe the anaconda's output to another program (`less`) so that the terminal doesn't close immediately before you see the output.